# Jqgrid - more bigger tittle bar

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid table and I want a more bigger title bar. I tried everything oh my ui.jqgrid.css file but nothing works. I have the normal settings in that file like:

```
   /*Grid*/
   .ui-jqgrid {position: relative;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {position: relative;left:0px; top: 0px; padding: .0em;  font-size:25px; }


   /* caption*/


    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {padding: .3em .2em .2em .3em; position: relative; border-left: 0px none;border-right: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-title { float: left; margin: .1em 0 .2em; }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close { position: absolute;top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height:18px;}.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close span { display: block; margin: 1px; }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close:hover { padding: 0; }



    /* header*/
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {position: relative; margin: 0em;padding: 0em; overflow- x: hidden; border-left: 0px none !important; border-top : 0px none !important; border-right  : 0px none !important; height: 30px;}

   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox {float: left; padding-right: 20px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable {table-layout:fixed;margin:0em;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {height:22px;padding: 0 2px 0 2px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {overflow: hidden; position:relative; height:17px;}
   .ui-th-column, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-align:center;border-top : 0px none;border-bottom : 0px none;}
   .ui-th-ltr, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-ltr {border-left : 0px none;}
   .ui-th-rtl, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-rtl {border-right : 0px none;}
   .ui-first-th-ltr {border-right: 1px solid; }
   .ui-first-th-rtl {border-left: 1px solid; }
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-th-div-ie {white-space: nowrap; zoom :1; height:17px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize {height:20px !important;position: relative; cursor :e-resize;display: inline;overflow: hidden;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-grid-ico-sort {overflow:hidden;position:absolute;display:inline; cursor: pointer !important;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-asc {margin-top:-3px; height:12px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-desc {margin-top:3px;height:12px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-i-asc {margin-top:0px;height:16px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-i-desc {margin-top:0px;margin-left:13px;height:16px;}
   .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sortable {cursor:pointer;}
   .ui-jqgrid tr.ui-search-toolbar th { border-top-width: 1px !important; border-top- color: inherit !important; border-top-style: ridge !important }
   tr.ui-search-toolbar input {margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px}
   tr.ui-search-toolbar select {margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px}
```

[image: Jqgrid]

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: The screenshort looks very strange. Do you used `<!DOCTYPE html ...` as the first line of your HTML file? Do you changed Font size with cSS having `!important` part? You wrote about the "tittle bar" in your question but one can see only column headers on the screenshort. Do you really want to increase height of "tittle bar" and not column header or some other elements?

Comment: well, I like to increase the height of that tiitle part (the blue part action, ciudad, corporacion, radicado etc) but I tried everything about the css without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included already two CSS lines from [ui.jqgrid.css](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css)

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {overflow: hidden; position:relative; height:17px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-div-ie {white-space: nowrap; zoom :1; height:17px;}
```

So to increase the height of the column headers you can use another fixed `height` value like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { height: 23px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-div-ie { height: 23px; }
```

or use `height: auto` style:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { height: auto; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-div-ie { height: auto; }
```

Comment: Im doing that oleg but the problem is that. .In fact the title bar increase its size but intead appear with the real size on the page an scroll appears.

Comment: Also we have to make another think in order to get this works:  we have to modify this line and set up the same hight as well:   `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {position: relative; margin: 0em;padding: 0em; overflow-x: hidden; border-left: 0px none !important; border-top : 0px none !important; border-right : 0px none !important; height: 50px;} ` thanks a lot @Oleg.

Comment: I Need your help buddy :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901762/jqgrid-custom-button-sending-post-data